# getting the PDG graph

Tags: frama-c

I'm developing a plugin in Frama-C and I want to get the Pdg graph from the C program. 
I tried the Db.Pdg.get which takes "kernel_function" type while I have a "funcdec" type. I didn't know how I fix that.
Any help?

Comment: If you tell us how you get the ``funcdec``, it might help to find out how you could get the ``kernel_function`` instead.

Comment: I get the "fundec" type from "globals" type which I get from "Cil_types.file".
I have as entry the AST of the C program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Globals.Functions.get fdec.Cil_types.svar` to convert a fundec `fdec` into a `kernel_function`. Calling `Db.Pdg.get` is then the right way to go.